# Array Sort Stops Too Soon

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to create two classes, one to define a point and another for array operations. I'm trying to create a method to sort an array of coordinates in ascending order based on y coordinates. I've tried following examples, but I keep running into a runtime error where the array is only partially sorted.

```
public class Point
    {
        private double x;
        private double y;

    public Point(double x_coord, double y_coord)
    {
        x = x_coord;
        y = y_coord;
    }
    public boolean lessThan(Point anotherPoint)
    {
        if(y < anotherPoint.y)
        {
            if(x < anotherPoint.x)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    }
    public class PointArray  
    {
    private Point[] points = new Point[count];

    public PointArray(double[] doubleArray)
    {
        if(doubleArray.length % 2 == 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 3; i++, j += 2)
            {
                double x = doubleArray[j];
                double y = doubleArray[j + 1];
                points[i] = new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error: The given array must be even.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public void sort()
    {
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        Point newPoint = new Point(x, y);
        Point temp = new Point(x, y);
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++)
            {
                int minIndex = i;
                if(points[minIndex].lessThan(points[j]) == false)
                {
                    temp = points[minIndex];
                    points[minIndex] = points[j];
                    points[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code causes the array `{5.6, 7.1, 4.9, 13.17, 9.3, 2.9}` to first be stored as ordered pairs `{(5.6, 7.1), (4.9, 13.17), (9.3, 2.9)}`. but it does not sort them properly. After the first and third points are swapped, the second and third are not, even though the y coordinate of the third is smaller.

```
[(9.3, 2.9), (4.9, 13.17), (5.6, 7.1)]
```

EDIT: Another issue appeared related to the same assignment. This method is supposed to take two PointArray objects and compare them for equality by the x and y components. My idea was to sort both arrays and then compare the components using a method in the Point class, but I'm not sure how to define each PointArray in terms of an (x, y) point.

```
public boolean equals(Point anotherPoint)
{
    if(x == anotherPoint.x && y == anotherPoint.y)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
  public boolean equals(PointArray anotherPointArray)
 {
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double xAnother = 0;
    double yAnother = 0;
    Point newPoint = new Point(x, y);
    Point newAnotherPoint = new Point(xAnother, yAnother);
    anotherPointArray.sort();


             for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
             {
                 for(int j = 0; i < points.length; j++)
                 {
                     if(newPoint.equals(newAnotherPoint))
                     {
                         return true;
                     }
                 }
             }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Simpler way is, you can implement `Comparable` interface in your `Point` class and override `compareTo(Object o)` method and define your comparision logic. Are you allowed to do that??

Comment: We haven't learned about that yet.

Comment: What exactly is your problem statement?

Comment: "boolean equals(PointArray anotherPointArray) : returns true if the invoking PointArray is equal to the argument PointArray. Two arrays of points are equal if all the points are the same. Note: order does not matter for equality;"

Comment: @JonathanGruver to your edit: please don't mutate the question. The original question was answered. "Another issue" means a new question.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, each of your `PointArray` object holds array of `Point` objects where each `Point` object has x and y coordinates.

Comment: I think that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `lessThan` method will give true only if both x and y are smaller. To sort by y alone use

```
public boolean lessThan(Point anotherPoint)
{
    return y < anotherPoint.y;
}
```